# What is returned by split when no delimiter is present

Tags: python, string

What is returned by the python split function when no delimiter is present? I'm thinking it must be a list with one element, which is the entire string. For instance

```
s = "700"
parts = s.split(".")
```

What is in `parts[0]`? Is it "700"? Or is it nothing?

My personal testing, what I've tried, indicates that `parts[0] = "700"`, but I want to be certain.

Comment: it is "700" which you can see if you tried it, if there is nothing to split you just get the string. It would make no sense at all to delete a string if it did not contain the delimiter

Comment: As I stated above, I did try it myself. I just was looking for someone to back up my own experience with it. I can't find it in the python doc. Just looking for some validation of my own experiment with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.split` just creates a string list, and when it hit your specified delimiter, it adds a new string to the list, which the following chars will be placed in, and so on. So if it doesn't hit the delimiter, everything will be at the first item of the array